# Mapreduce job failing even the required class is present

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Hi my job is failing due to runtime exception, saying, mapper class not found.

Below is the exception:

```
14/06/16 05:52:56 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201406071432_1142_m_000028_0, Status : FAILED
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.cloudera.sa.omniture.mr.OmnitureRawDataMapper not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1774)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getMapperClass(JobContextImpl.java:191)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:631)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:330)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.cloudera.sa.omniture.mr.OmnitureRawDataMapper not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1680)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1772)
        ... 8 more
```

But in my jar i used to run the job had the Mapper class present, still i am facing the issue. pls guide.

Below info. on my jar file confirms the presence of Mapper class in jar file.

```
[svtdphpd@d-hcr75y1 testJARs]$ jar tvf MalformedAnalysis.jar | grep Omniture
  1405 Mon Jun 16 15:59:34 CDT 2014 com/cloudera/sa/omniture/mr/OmnitureRawDataMapper$HITDATA_PROBLEM.class
  3728 Mon Jun 16 15:59:34 CDT 2014 com/cloudera/sa/omniture/mr/OmnitureRawDataMapper.class
  5280 Mon Jun 16 16:00:46 CDT 2014 com/cloudera/sa/omniture/mr/OmnitureToRCFileJob.class
  6436 Mon Jun 16 16:03:34 CDT 2014 com/cloudera/sa/omniture/mr/OmnitureDataFileRecordReader.class
  3642 Mon Jun 16 16:00:16 CDT 2014 com/cloudera/sa/omniture/mr/OmnitureRawDataReducer.class
  1792 Mon Jun 16 15:59:34 CDT 2014 com/cloudera/sa/omniture/mr/OmnitureDataFileInputFormat.class
```

Below is the Job configuration:

```
// Create job
Job job = Job.getInstance(config, "LoadOmnitureData");
job.setJarByClass(OmnitureToRCFileJob.class);

// Add named output for malformed records

MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "Malformed",
        TextOutputFormat.class, NullWritable.class, Text.class);

FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(inputPath));

job.setInputFormatClass(OmnitureDataFileInputFormat.class);     
job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

job.setOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

job.setReducerClass(OmnitureRawDataReducer.class);
job.setMapperClass(OmnitureRawDataMapper.class);

job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

TextOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(outputPath));

job.setNumReduceTasks(numReduceTasks);
```

Comment: How do you run the job. Show the command you use

Comment: hadoop jar MalformedAnalysis.jar com.cloudera.sa.omniture.mr.OmnitureToRCFileJob tcomprodarchives/20140518 tcomprodconsumables/20140518

Comment: Also share your job configuration files

Comment: My Jar file is having that Mapper class still its failing with ClassNotFoundException....  :S

Comment: @Jijo added job configuration...